# Stalk at a point of the sheaf of open sets

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory

Fix a base topological space $X$.

For every open subset $U$ of $X$, define $\mathcal F(U)$ to be the set of open subsets of $U$.

The restriction map $\mathcal F(V) \to \mathcal F(U)$ sends $W$ to $W \cap U$.

This defines a sheaf.

Is there a nice description of the stalk at each point? I understand that it should depend on the particular point, but is there a nice description still?

If no, would there be a nice description assuming some separation axioms?

Comment: The stalk at any given point $x$ contains one point representing the neighbourhoods of $x$, that are all identified, a point representing $\emptyset$ (these are all the open sets whose closure doesn't contain $x$); and then many other points representing the open sets whose closure contains $x$ but that aren't neighbourhoods of $x$. Thus I would say this depends on the actual topology of $X$, not only on the separation axioms

Comment: Let's say, what is the stalk at each point in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: A good thing about $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that it's homogeneous, so the stalk won't depend on the point, so we may ask what the stalk at $0$ is. But it seems hard even for $\mathbb{R}$. Put $F_0$ the stalk at $0$, then for instance $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n<\omega}(u_{n+1},u_n)$ will correspond to a point of $F_0$ for any positive  decreasing sequence $u$ converging to $0$, and two sequences that are essentially different will correspond to different points in $F_0$: there will be many different points in $F_0$. The question looks very hard to me (but maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: Shouldn't the stalk just be a point if the space is locally contractible? Or at least a manifold

Comment: @leibnewtz why ? There are always at least two points: the "open sets far from $x$" point, and the "neighbourhoods of $x$" point. Then according to the topology of $X$ there may be more (in $\mathbb{R}$, the stalk at $0$ will contain tons of points as I've explained earlier, and $\mathbb{R}$ is very very locally contractible)

Comment: Won't two representatives $(x,U)$ and $(y, V)$ represent the same class if there exists $(z,W)$ with $W \subseteq U \cap V$ such that $x \cap W =z$ and $y \cap W=z$? Why not choose $W=x \cap y$ and $z=W$?

Comment: Because $U \cap V$ can be empty, but the first coordinate must be a neighbourhood

Comment: @leibnewtz I don't understand what you mean by $(x,U)$. All I know is that, when looking at the stalk at $0$ (say in $\mathbb{R}$) we look at open sets containg $0$, look at their $\mathcal{F}(U)$, and some $W\in \mathcal{F}(U)$ is identified in the stalk to $V\in\mathcal{F}(U')$ if and only if for some open neighbourhood of $0$, $O$ included in $U\cap U'$, $W\cap O = V\cap O$. Now for $(-\epsilon, 0)$ and $(0,\epsilon)$ that are in $\mathcal{F}((-\epsilon, \epsilon))$ I can hardly see how they can be identified.

Comment: Right my mistake was in assuming $x \cap y$ contained the point

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that this is the sheaf of continuous functions to the Sierpinski space.